# SELECT, group, limit based on month

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am using this: `SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY ident order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3`.

I use that to group each ident from sales table, and count the number of rows for each ident, and limit this to 3 rows. Now I want to only select the rows that were added the current month.

This is how the table looks like, **sales** table:

```
| ID |   ident  |  prdnr  |       transfer      |
| 1  |   HD762  | 7362781 | 2020-08-10 16:25:26 |
| 2  |   JJ313  | 4563456 | 2020-08-08 16:25:26 |
| 3  |   HD762  | 4363453 | 2020-08-08 16:25:26 |
| 4  |   JJ313  | 2326256 | 2020-08-08 16:25:26 |
| 5  |   HD762  | 8356345 | 2020-08-07 16:25:26 |
| 6  |   JJ844  | 3473563 | 2020-08-07 16:25:26 |
```

I think this should be the correct query:

```
SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE MONTH(transfer) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(transfer) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY ident order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Somehow this does not gives me the correct count. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should be part of the WHERE, not the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `AND` in the `GROUP BY` clause probably makes very little sense, I’m guessing. If you have multiple grouping criteria, then they need to be listed _comma-separated_.

Comment: Where's the month column?

Comment: The datetime column named `transfer` is all I have.

Comment: I've posted an answer , i'm not sure your expected result. But do let me know if it helps else i'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement , a simple way is getting the MySQL current time and subtract a month to get the values

The code :-

> SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE  transfer > date_sub(now(),
> interval 1 month) GROUP BY ident order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3;

The output from the query

```
HD762   3
JJ313   2
JJ844   1
```

Please let me know if this is the expected result you're looking for.

Reference :-
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Nice! A question; Now it is week numer 33, can this be done to get sales added the current week number also?

Comment: @Camilla, Yeah, you can . I just tested the query with 33 weeks instead of 1 month. I've attached the reference in my answer. If my answer helps , feel free to vouch it

Comment: Warning, the past 4 weeks only equal the current month on the 28th of February. :)

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagyi, i agree with you. It goes by mathematical whereby 1 week has 7 days.

Comment: What I mean is that on the 15th of a month, the past 4 weeks include the time since the 18th (or so) of last month. I assume the OP needs 1st-31st.